# Get Remote Web Server Information (Fingerprint) Using PHP

Tags: php

Would like to get web server information of a remote web server using php.  for example: www.foo.com would produce -->

Apache/2.2.13 (FreeBSD) mod_ssl/2.2.13 OpenSSL/0.9.8e DAV/2 
PHP/5.2.11 with Suhosin-Patch

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
$info = get_headers($url);
```

$info will then contain an array of the headers sent by that site. You can pick and choose what info you want to keep from it, or if you want it all as a string:

```
$string = implode(' ', $info);
```

See [get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) info here.

**Note** - you can only get as much information as is revealed by the remote server. If they've chosen to hide this information, you can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed -->

```
<?php $info = get_headers($url);

$string0 = implode(' ', $info);
$string1 = explode('Server:', $string0);

//BEGIN EXTRACTING SERVER DETAILS
$pattern = '#^Server:#i';
$matches = preg_grep($pattern, $info);
?>
```